# Cast to signed smallint in mysql/mariadb

Tags: mysql, casting, mariadb

I have some data stored as an unsigned smallint (in mariadb).  Most times, I'd rather view this as a signed smallint.  Is there any way to cast an unsigned smallint to a signed smallint?

The 'CAST' function does not behave as expected for converting between signs.  It is clearly intended to convert between strings and numbers, and does not even support smallint as an arguement.

Is the best way to do this with hand coded logic?  Such as :

`IF( number > 32767, number - 65536, number )`

or am I missing some sort of built in mysql functionality?

Comment: What is the difference/importance in viewing the data as signed versus unsigned? Or do you mean that you actually have signed integers stored as unsigned, and want to convert the high bit to a sign?

Comment: Correct.  I would like to convert the high bit to the sign.  I ended up making a function to do this based on the IF statement, but I'd rather use a mysql builtin if it exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked for a while and haven't found any builtin way to do this.  If anyone else comes across this problem, I ended up defining my own function that looked something like:

```
CREATE FUNCTION `unsignedSmallIntToSignedSmallInt`(n SMALLINT UNSIGNED) RETURNS SMALLINT
RETURN IF( n > 32767, n - 65536, n );
```